What options are there for multiplying clock pulses by non-harmonic values?
I have a MIDI clock signal which will output pulses at 24ppqn and a device I would like to synchronise which runs at 64ppqn. This is equivalent to a an ⁸⁄₃ clock multiplication.
My current method is to divide by 2 with a flip-flop to get a square wave from the pulses,
multiply by 16 using a PLL then finally divide by 3 using two flip-flops and a NOR gate. In combination with using the MIDI stop/start commands to reset the flip-flops this should create the desired frequency with synchronised phase.
I would like to know if there are any alternative methods for doing this as it seems quite elaborate.

There are fractional-N PLL's that could just multiply by 8/3 in one step, but I don't know if they're appropriate for use with MIDI. What is the clock frequency in Hz?

Take a look at the DCO oscillator peripheral of the MSP430. If has all you need and so much more. And cheaply.

frequency range of input is between 5-150Hz roughly.

What is ppqn? parts per quadrillion!?

I have never used MSP430 but it looks interesting, it says in these two application notes however that the DCO range starts at 1MHz. Is there a way to use the DCO at frequencies down to DC?
https://www.ti.com/lit/ab/slaa791/slaa791.pdf
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa992/slaa992.pdf

ppqn stands for pulses per quarter note, used in MIDI

The MIDI standard specifies 24ppqn. In ⁴⁄₄ time signature the tempo of a song is defined as how many quarter notes occur in a minute, known as BPM or beats per minute.

@Pernel_Sned You can very very easily use the DCO for very low frequencies. I used it to stay phase-locked to the 60 Hz AC zero-crossover (120 Hz events that wander this way and that), for example. You can chain peripherals together inside the chip and/or write software. In my case I wanted to use phase control and this provided me with a fixed integer that always represented exactly 1/2 cycle. Made phase control really easy. I would use techniques I can't easily describe here to predict the next count at the current rate and added a slow rate twiddling of the DCO to stay on target over time.

ok great I'll give it a go, thanks

@Pernel_Sned Best wishes!! Go for it.
